# Which is correct: "I am drinking ice cream" or "I am eating ice cream"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

Assuming there is no material in ice cream to be chewed, which is the correct sentence?

> I am drinking ice cream.
>
> I am eating ice cream.

Comment: [Ice cream](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/ice+cream) is a frozen dessert that is eaten. Drinks that contain ice cream are usually a [float](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/float_2) or [milkshake](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/milkshake). You would drink a float or milkshake, but eat ice cream.

Comment: For all you New Englanders out there, @aedia is referring to a _[frappe](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2009/09/milk-shakes.html)_.

Comment: You eat ice cream. But if you wait long enough, you drink it :-)

Comment: This isn't really a question about English.  We all know what ice-cream is and the difference between eating and drinking.  But still, someone has favourited it.

Comment: @z7sgѪ, I think it comes from the fact that in some languages you drink ice cream, as in Portuguese «**tomar** sorvete», though you wouldn't use *beber*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are eating ice cream. You also eat soup, applesauce, yogurt, and many other things. The "food" category is not defined by chewability.

Comment: +1. Food is eaten, drinks are drunk. This is true even when eating soup and drinking a milkshake; the food is more liquid than the drink, but the verbs still agree.

Comment: @KeithS: You can drink soup just fine. (At least, you could where I grew up.)

Comment: you drink soup out of a mug, you eat soup out of a bowl with a spoon.

Comment: @jk: You can drink soup of out a bowl by, well, drinking it. As in, no spoon; just the bowl.

Comment: shouldn't it be eating "an" icecream ? You missed out the "AN" ????

Answer (score 11):

Ice cream is typically eaten. If you melted the ice cream, you could *probably* drink it. Similar foods get differing treatment and the pattern usually comes down utensils:

- You drink through a straw (slurpies, shakes)
- You eat with a spoon (ice cream, pudding, soup)
- You drink from a bowl by tipping it to your mouth (soup, broth)

Comment: @phenry: I'm not sure I understand your point? That people more often eat soup with a spoon than drink it from a bowl?

Comment: I think humans eat from a bowl; if they drink, then the bowl is called a cup.

Comment: @Henry: People drink from bowls all the time. And they do not suddenly call the bowl a cup. Just because _you_ don't do it doesn't mean others don't.

Comment: if you are picking up the bowl to your lips then yes that's drinking, if you are using a spoon then that is eating

Comment: @Henry: I think MrHen's third choice is a type mismatch, it doesn't really belong. Whether it's a bowl, plate or shallow in a tin rooftop, if you use a spoon you're eating, but by straw or straight with your lips, you're drinking. So one can then infer that if you tip up a bowl to your lips directly, you're drinking the soup (since one usually doesn't do that in primarily-English-speaking societies, it's most likely that one _eats soup from a bowl_ since they'll most likely be using a spoon. An thick milkshake in a tall glass? Using a spoon, I would be _eating_ it.

Comment: @Mitch: Ugh, fine. I added a clarification. BTW, where I grew was the primarily-English-speaking society of the American Midwest. We drank soup all the time. This is _exactly_ why I mentioned utensils in the answer _and_ included soup in the spoon category. The type of food matters less than the utensils/method of consumption. You could drink bacon if you pureed it and stuck in it a cup or you could eat coffee one spoonful at a time.

Comment: @MrHen: Yes, I am now aware that my analysis isn't quite right (see comments to Harrold's answer: you eat an ice cream cone even though there are no utensils involved, and yes...um... logically it would work that under soome strange circumstances something like bacon could be drunk).

Answer (score 4):

"Eat" would be the right word unless you want to specifically emphasize that it's melting before you have a chance to consume it (e.g., "Between the heat and my 2 year-old acting out, I ended up drinking my ice cream.")

Answer (score 2):

Ice cream is eaten as it is in solid state. You can not drink ice, can you?

Comment: I can drink ice cream but not ice cube. :-)

Comment: @xport Well, when one says ice cream, it is usually meant to be in solid state, otherwise it is melted ice cream. You can drink it after you melt it in your mouth, granted, but you can hardly do so quickly with a big amount of it. (I am using laic terms as you are most probably interested in the usage of language rather than the phyics.)

Comment: The more interesting question is the difference between soft-serve ice cream and a milkshake.

Comment: @Random832: re my comment to MrHen's answer...my analsysis falls apart with the soft-serve ice cream (I know that it is _eaten_ but the logic I stated says it is drunk. How do I fix the analysis?)

Comment: Ice cream is part solid, part liquid, and part gas. The sugar stops it fully freezing, unless you make it very cold, and there's often also a significant amount of air.