# Does one eat soup or drink soup?

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct verb associated with the consumption of soup? 
I've come across both the version.

Comment: **Eat** here is general and I believe more formal.

Comment: [Funny discussion on the same topic](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1615441&langid=18)

Comment: Related: [“I am drinking ice cream” vs. “I am eating ice cream”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34341/which-is-correct-i-am-drinking-ice-cream-or-i-am-eating-ice-cream), whose answers actually explicitly mention soup. I'm not quite sure what the question here is in the first place. When you eat soup, then you eat it. When you drink it, then that's what you do. I hope I don't have to explain how drinking is different from eating. So this is very much like asking whether "drive a car" or "wash a car" is correct.

Comment: Interesting - I thought it was only in Japanese that you drank a soup!

Comment: @RegDwigнt In other languages, consuming soup is always used with the verb drink rather than eat; no matter the means of consumption. **I believe the question is about what is the "default" verb that should be used in English when consuming soup.** I think we can all agree that if you put soup in a cup and drink it, you would be drinking soup. However, when you ask your friend (in English) if he wants to go "drink soup," it sounds silly (to me at least). On the other hand, in other languages, even if a spoon and bowl are used, "drink" is the norm; and "eating soup" would sound silly to them.

Answer (score 6):

In US English, either *eat* or *drink* could be used with soup.  I hadn't noticed it before, but although you generally *drink* liquids, you *eat* with a spoon, so you would *drink* a *cup* of soup and *eat* a *bowl* of soup.

Comment: I _drink broth_ but _eat soup._

Comment: ... and carefully steer clear of bisque, chowder, consommé ...?

Answer (score 0):

"having soup" would be more generalized. what do you say?

Comment: Yep - most people chicken out.

Comment: yup when you are confused then so its better to chicken out than to be embarrassed ;)